# Javascript: Adding '<' seems to break html

Tags: javascript

I have a scenario where i have strings which have the character '<' in it. An example of this is

```
<a href='#'>foobar</a> foo <bar
```

Using the native JavaScript (`innerHTML`) as well as jQuery (`.html()`), while trying to add it to the DOM, the text after and including < gets stripped off

```
<a href='#'>foobar</a> foo
```

I tried escaping the '<' however that escapes the `<a>` as well. Anchors are not the only html tag that may be there, so how can i handle in such a way that i can only encode the '<' that are not part of any html entity.

An example of the problem - http://jsfiddle.net/ovbg3p8m/

Please note i get the entire HTML from somewhere else and have to work with that.

Thanks.

Comment: You can escape `<` with `&lt;`.

Comment: I get the string in the form `<` and cannot do anything about that. I need to  work with that

Answer (score 1):

You can use `&lt;` instead for a less than symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Use `&lt;`, not `<`.      .

Answer (score 0):

Try using the appropriate entry from the HTML name column [here](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm).

Comment: I saw you had problems formatting your answer. StackOverflow parses HTML, unless you [format it as code](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). You can use `\`` or add indentation to create a code block.

Comment: Thank you, I'll bear that in mind, but I also wanted to  correct it with a more general answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
&lt;
```

is the escaping you desire for this symbol.
The key is to escape what needs to be escaped and not the  tag as that is html you want to preserve.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your build your HTML like:

```
var text = "foo <bar";
var link_text = "foobar";
var html = '<a href="#">' + link_text + '</a>' + text;
$(".node").html(html);
```

If you escape just `text` and `link_text` (but not `html`) you're good.

The distinction between what is html and what isn't is very important.

---

In PHP there is the function [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) which replaces `&, ", ', <` and `>` by their escaped forms: `&amp; &quot; &apos; &lt; &gt;`. This is sufficient to avoid breaking HTML.

Comment: I get the entire html in one shot from somewhere else and need to work with that.

Comment: Then that supplier has to escape the `<`. You're essentially getting malformed HTML.

Answer (score 0):

you have to escape the <

```
var text = '<a href="#">foobar</a> foo &#60;bar foobar';
```

Find more here
[Escape html](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

Comment: As mentioned above i get the entire text from somewhere else. So i have to work with the what i get. So in your above case `<a` will also get converted as `&#60;a`